# loopback send email with attachment not working

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, email-attachments, strongloop, nodemailer

I have the career PersistedModel for storing the data in the database and i have the attachment model for file storage to store in some location.Now i want to send an email with the data. I can able to send only the career data but i want to send attachment also with the same email.I could not able to fetch the file name because it is not in the career model it is in the attachment. How to do get the file name and send it help me out.

career.js

```
const app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Career) {
    Career.afterRemote('create', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) { 
        next(); 
       console.log(remoteMethodOutput) 
    Career.app.models.Email.send({ 
            to: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
            from: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
            subject: 'my subject', 
            html: 'Hello-world',
            attachments: [
             {  
            path: '../files/resume/'+remoteMethodOutput.resume,
             }
             ],
            }, function(err, mail) { 
                // console.log(context.result.email)
            console.log('email sent!'); 
            cb(err); 
        }); 
    }); 
};
```

attachment.json

```
{
  "name": "attachment",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

My project structure where i used to store the files is

[image]

Comment: What does `console.log(remoteMethodOutput) ` log?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute path for your files is always more robust than relative path. Use `__dirname` for that :

```
const filePath = __dirname + '/files/resume/' + remoteMethodOutput.resume;
```

If you need to go up one level, then enter the `files` directory, you need Node's `path` module to resolve it :

```
const path = require("path"),
      filePath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../files/resume/' + remoteMethodOutput.resume)
```

Comment: but am not getting the file name. it shows undefined

Comment: Hence my question : What does `console.log(remoteMethodOutput)` log?

Comment: it print the values of that form like name..etc